# bash script gives error with mv ... probably easy fix

Tags: bash, variables, hyperlink, awk

EDIT: the fixnames.sh called at the end is probably generating the error (particularly line 2):

```
    #/bin/bash
    for x in *\'*;
    do
    y=$(echo "$x"| sed y/\'\,/__/)
    mv "$x" "$y"
    done
```

The problem line is the mv command at the end

```
    mv $OUTDIR/$OLD $OUTDIR/$NEW
```

It errors with something like:

```
    mv '*\* [something about unable to stat this]
```

This script was something I customized from one that had been posted here http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Removing_Commercials and some other places.  The goal of the mv was, iirc, to clean up the tmp directory (removing a symbolic link that I clunkily used to do a rename of the file).  I'm a little unclear on what is happening in that mv line and the 2 lines prior that is apparently causing the script not to finish cleanly.  Thanks for any input.

```
    #!/bin/sh
    VIDEODIR=$1
    FILENAME=$2
    CHANID=$3
    STARTTIME=$4
    # MythTV Install Prefix
    INSTALLPREFIX="/usr/bin"
    USRLOCALPREFIX="/usr/local/bin"
    HOMEDIR="/home/xxx"
    OUTDIR="/home/xxx/trans-out"
    TMPDIR="/home/xxx/trans-out/tmp"

    if [ ! -d $TMPDIR ]; then mkdir $TMPDIR; fi
    rm -f $TMPDIR/*

    # Sanity checking, to make sure everything is in order.
    if [ -z "$VIDEODIR" -o -z "$FILENAME" -o -z "$CHANID" -o -z "$STARTTIME" ]; then
            echo "Usage: $0 <VideoDirectory> <FileName> <CHANID> <STARTTIME>"
            exit 5
    fi
    if [ ! -f "$VIDEODIR/$FILENAME" ]; then
            echo "File does not exist: $VIDEODIR/$FILENAME"
            exit 6
    fi
    # The meat of the script. Flag commercials, copy the flagged commercials to
    # the cutlist, and transcode the video to remove the commercials from the
    # file.

    $INSTALLPREFIX/mythtranscode --chanid $CHANID --starttime $STARTTIME --mpeg2 --honorcutlist --showprogress -o $OUTDIR/$FILENAME.tmp
    ERROR=$?
    if [ $ERROR -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "Transcoding failed for ${FILENAME} with error $ERROR"
            exit $ERROR
    fi

    # use mythlink script to extract program information from database and make link in tmp subfolder for renaming of transcoded version.
    $USRLOCALPREFIX/mythlink.pl --link $TMPDIR --chanid $CHANID --starttime $STARTTIME --underscores --separator _ --format %T_%oY%om%od_%S

    # remove the map file since we are transcoding
    rm -f $OUTDIR/$FILENAME.tmp.map

    # set variables for newfilename-link and oldfilename-transcoded file and then to rename transcoded with link name
    NEW=$(ls $TMPDIR)
    OLD=$(ls $OUTDIR | grep -i "mpg.tmp" | awk '{ print $1; }')
    mv $OUTDIR/$OLD $OUTDIR/$NEW

    # remove commas and apostraphies
    cd $OUTDIR && $USRLOCALPREFIX/fixnames.sh
```

Comment: "errors with something like" is much less useful than copying and pasting the error.  Is the switch from slash to backslash real, or your re-typing error?  What about the un-closed quote?

Comment: These are REALLY useful hints/helps - thanks very much ghoti and Ed.  The exact error was:  "mv: cannot stat `*\'*': No such file or directory" ... Based on the excellent suggestions received, I'll get this script fixed up and post back with results soon.  Again, huge thanks to you both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this

```
NEW=$(ls $TMPDIR)
OLD=$(ls $OUTDIR | grep -i "mpg.tmp" | awk '{ print $1; }')
mv $OUTDIR/$OLD $OUTDIR/$NEW
```

is telling me is that your ".mpg.tmp" files resides in `/home/xxx/trans-out`, and you're trying to move them (probably renamed to ".mpg" too?) to `/home/xxx/trans-out/tmp` (overwriting ".mpg" files with the same name?).

As to why it's not working, assume that `NEW` and `OLD` does indeed contain the list of files as you intended:

- `NEW` contains "new1", "new2", "new3"
- `OLD` contains "old1", "old2", "old3"

The statement `mv $OUTDIR/$OLD $OUTDIR/$NEW` would then expand to

```
mv $OUTDIR/new1 new2 new3 old1 $OUTDIR/old2 old3
```

which would mean: move the 5 files ("$OUTDIR/new1", "new2", "new3", "old1", "$OUTDIR/old2") to the directory "old3".

---

What I suspect would work is replacing that 3 lines with this

```
for tmpfile in "$OUTDIR"/*.mpg.tmp; do
    mv "$tmpfile" "$TMPDIR/${tmpfile%.tmp}"
done
```

(I assumed that the `awk` was for removing '.tmp' from the extension)

Answer (score 4):

This whole script should really be refactored.  Constructs like `NEW=$(ls $TMPDIR)` are very very bad.  See [ParsingLS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for details.

Just looking at the offensive part of your script for a moment...

```
# set variables for newfilename-link and oldfilename-transcoded file and then to rename transcoded with link name
NEW=$(ls $TMPDIR)
OLD=$(ls $OUTDIR | grep -i "mpg.tmp" | awk '{ print $1; }')
mv $OUTDIR/$OLD $OUTDIR/$NEW
```

My read on this, in meta-code, is:

- store the filenames of everything in $TMPDIR to the variable $NEW
- store some portion of a subset of the files in $OUTDIR to the variable $OLD
- move all the (mangled) filenames ... to $TMPDIR?

This doesn't make much sense to me.  Do you *really* have files that end in `" mpg.tmp"` (with the space)?  And additional files with the matching preceding bit, but without the `" mpg.tmp"`?

If you can describe, with example filenames, what you want done, it should be easy enough to re-write these three lines of code so they work.

For additional wisdom, try the following:

```
NEW=$(ls $TMPDIR)
OLD=$(ls $OUTDIR | awk '/mpg\.tmp/{ print $1; }')
echo "mv $OUTDIR/$OLD $OUTDIR/$NEW" >> /tmp/mytherror.log
mv $OUTDIR/$OLD $OUTDIR/$NEW
```

And see what turns up in `/tmp/mytherror.log`.

Note that I am **not** advocating that you use `var=$(ls ...)` constructs.  Those should be removed.  They're dangerous.  But let's learn what's actually happening first.

Comment: OK, goal for this offending section is to rename /home/xxx/trans-out/TRANSCODEDFILE.mpg.tmp with the actual name of the .mpg as pulled from the database (making result /home/xxx/trans-out/Great_Muppet_Caper.mpg)  ...  The way this is currently done (cludge alert) is to make  mythlink.pl create a link in the /tmp subdirectory and then rename /home/xxx/trans-out/TRANSCODEDFILE.mpg.tmp (transcoded file) with link name.  So, let me be clear that it WORKS (renames the file somehow), but throws the error "mv: cannot stat `*\'*': No such file or directory".  So, I'm trying to clean this up.

Comment: added echo "mv $OUTDIR/$OLD $OUTDIR/$NEW" >> /tmp/mytherror.log which did create the error log under /tmp, but it only yielded as contents: "mv /home/xxx/trans-out/2692_20121015020000.mpg.tmp /home/xxx/trans-out/Scream_of_Fear_00000000__Untitled.mpg"

Comment: Okay... and that move looks pretty normal.  Did you see the "cannot stat" error for this run?  Is it possible that it's being generated by `fixnames.sh` instead?

Comment: NOOB city.  Yes, fixnames is probably the problem.  Particularly:     #/bin/bash

        for x in *\'*;
        
        do
        
        y=$(echo "$x"| sed y/\'\,/__/)
        
        # echo "$y"
        mv "$x" "$y"
        
        done

Comment: @jojo - no worries, glad it's solved.  If my answer helped, please feel free to click the checkmark beside it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

ALWAYS quote your variables unless you have a good, specific reason not to and understand the effects. mv $OLD $NEW is a very different command from mv "$OLD" "$NEW" and probably not what you want. So, quote your variables, re-run your script and come back if it still has problems.

Comment: I'm such a bash noob, I had no idea of this quoting rule.  On my list to do get some basic knowledge like this under the belt.  Thanks Ed, and sorry to drag these basic errors in here.